# How to make jquery row non editable and save the same row in Database using ajax call?

Tags: java, javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I made the inline edit true for jqGrid by using below code -

```
 if (rowid) {
      if (rowid !== lastsel) {
          $("#prjectForecastData").jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
          $("#prjectForecastData").jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true);
          lastsel = rowid;
       } else {
              $("#prjectForecastData").jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
              lastsel = "";
          }
    }
```

But here in below code, while saving row, I want to make an ajax call in order to save that row in database. and also want to make that row non editable.
Right now `'clientArray'` is used to save the value on browser temporarily.But unable to  make it non editable after that.

```
$("#saveForecastEditData").click(function(){
     $("#prjectForecastData").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel, false, 'clientArray');
       jQuery('#prjectForecastData').editRow(lastsel,false);
});
```

So how to make an ajax call and make the row non editable after saving the row in DB successfully?

Answer (score 1):

To make row non-editable you should add `not-editable-row` class to the corresponding row. The exact code can depend on jqGrid configuration which you use. For example you can just add the line

```
$("#" + lastsel).addClass("not-editable-row");
```

after the line with `saveRow`, but sorting or paging of local data will **recreate** the grid body and so it will remove any previously set classes or rows of the grid. To make the information persistent you can save it in local `data` together with the main data. For example you can do the following

```
$("#saveForecastEditData").click(function () {
    var $myGrid = $("#prjectForecastData"), rowData;
    $myGrid.jqGrid("saveRow", lastsel, { url: "clientArray"});
    rowData = $myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", lastsel);
    // add new property to the data
    rowData.modified = true;
    // add the "not-editable-row" immediately
    $("#" + lastsel).addClass("not-editable-row");
});
```

The code of `"#prjectForecastData"` grid can use `rowattr`:

```
$("#prjectForecastData").jqGrid({
    // ... all your existing parameters here
    rowattr: function (rowData) {
        if (rowData.modified) {
            return {"class": "not-editable-row"};
        }
    }
});
```

It will restore the class `"not-editable-row"` on rows which was modified locally.

To get all modified rows and to send there to the server one can use the following code

```
var data = $("#prjectForecastData").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
var modifiedData = $.grep(data, function (item) { return item.modified; } );
$.ajax({
    url: "someServerUtl",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        modifications: JSON.stringify(modifiedData)
    }
});
```

The exact parameters of `$.ajax` request will depend on your server code which get the data.

In the way you will save **all modified data** using one ajax call. Alternativaly you can just use another (server based) `url` in the call of `saveRow`. In the case the data of one saved row will be automatically send to the server on in the format described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server).