# How to remove inline edit button so that save and cancel buttons remain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In free jqgrid inline edit of row is started using single click in row in `beforeSelectRow` event.

So inline edit button in actions column is not needed.
I tried to remove it by setting `editbutton = false` in formatoptions:

```
  cm= [{
    "name":"_actions",
    "template":"actions",
    "formatoptions":{"editbutton":false,
    "delbutton":true,
    "delOptions":{"url":"Delete",
    "afterComplete":function (response, postdata, formid) { 
       $grid[0].focus(); 
       }
      }}}
```

In this case save and cancel buttons also do not appear in actions column during inline edit. Actions column is empty on inline edit.

How to enable save and cancel action buttons if edit action button is disabled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you mean that Save, button should be included in `formatter: "action"`, but be hidden till the editing will be started in the line (by usage button of `inlineNav`, by selection of the row or by some other way). You can do this in free jqGrid by usage `isDisplayButtons` callback (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735149/315935)). The following definition of the column do the trick

```
{
    name: "_actions",
    template: "actions",
    formatoptions: {
        editbutton: false,
        isDisplayButtons: function (opts, rwd, act) {
            return {
                save: { display: true },
                cancel: { display: true }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ActionButtonsCustomization.htm):

[image]

In general you can display visible Save button in all rows by usage of

```
{
    name: "_actions",
    template: "actions",
    formatoptions: {
        editbutton: false,
        isDisplayButtons: function (opts, rwd, act) {
            return {
                save: { display: true, hidden: false },
                cancel: { display: true }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

(see [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ActionButtonsCustomization0.htm)), but the Save buttons will be hidden after editing saving of the row changes because `formatter: "actions"` synchronize the visibility of buttons with the current state of the row:

[image]