# JQGrid automatically hide a row with a false in a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to hide a Row if a cell in it has the false value, so far I've tried using a formatter like this:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
            //datatype: 'clientSide',
            colNames: ["Id", "Descrizione", "Data Vendita", "Disabilitato", "PISTA", 
                       "Piano Tariffario", "Data Validità Piano Tariffario", 
                       "PROMO", "Data Validità Promo", "CANONE CLIENTE NETTO MESE", 
                       "Vendibile", "Migrato"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "id"},
                { name: "descrizione", editable: true},
                { name: "dataInizVendita", editable: true, formatter:vendita},                          
                { name: "disabilitato", editable: true},
                { name: "pista", editable: true},
                { name: "pianoTariffario", editable: true},
                { name: "dataInizPiano", editable: true, formatter:piano},              
                { name: "promo", editable: true},
                { name: "dataInizPromo", editable: true, formatter:promo},
                { name: "canoneNetto", editable: true},
                { name: "disponibilita", editable: true, formatter:mostra},
                { name: "migrato", editable: true, width:150, sortable: false, resizable:false, formatter:bottone}          
            ],
            formatter: 'date', 
            formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'},
            sortname: "id",
            sortorder: "asc"

        })
```

The formatter that I care about is mostra, if disponibilita is false, it must hide the row!

```
function mostra (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{               

    if(rowObject.disponibilita == false)
    {               
        $("#"+rowObject.id).hide();
    }
    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
    return rowObject.disponibilita;
}
```

I've tried using delRowdata too, but it doesn't remove it, and it can see when it's false and when it's not, because the if function works perfectly

Comment: Do you plan to delete the question next time like [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295729/jqgrid-open-another-page-on-clicking-a-custom-edit-button/35295971#35295971)? The current question don't describe which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use. One can just delete the item of data *before* it will be used by jqGrid, but the solution depends on the `datatype` which you use. The usage of `rowattr` is alternative

Comment: 1) I deleted the question because I saw no answers and my question was wrong in the first place
2) I used the rowattr as you suggested, in the class I try to hide the row using
.ui-widget-content .rowClass { display:"none";  }
but it doesn't hide it, does it have a specific command to hide it?

Comment: nevermind, it should be display: none;......

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't know which `datatype` you use and which version of jqGrid you use. The preferred way will be deleting the item from the data instead of hiding it, but one have to know the requested information. If you do use `rowattr` then you should post the code, which you tried and which is not worked. Because I have no other information I show how you can use `rowattr` correctly in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better **to delete** the data, which have `false` value in `disponibilita` column **before** the data will be processed by jqGrid. In case of `datatype: "local"` one should just modify the input data and then use `data` parameter with modifies input. In case of loading the data from the server one can use `beforeProcessing` callback to modify the data returned from the server.

Only if you can't implement the above scenarios because of some additional reasons, you can use `rowattr` callback in the following form

```
rowattr: function (item) { // !rowObject.disponibilita in your case
    if (item.closed) {
        return {style: "display:none;"};
    }
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/hideByStyle.htm) or in "class" form:

```
rowattr: function (item) {
    if (item.closed) {
        return {"class": "my-hide"};
    }
}
```

see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/hideByClass.htm). You can see then both of the solutions works, but the page size is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to use an each function to scan the tr and td data and hide when false

```
$('.hidefalse').click(function() {

$("#grid tr").each(function () {
var thisrow = $(this);

    $('td', this).each(function () {
        var value = $(this).text();

        if (value == 'false') {
            $(thisrow).fadeOut();
        }
     })

})

})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zhm5ephu/)

To automate it take out the click function

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74hf0dvx/)