# Delete Button jqgrid in just few rows

Tags: jqgrid

How do I set the delete button in just a few lines?

My list is returned by json and some records do not need the delete button. 
How do I remove it from PHP?

Thks.

EDITED

I SOLVED

```
 loadComplete: function () {
    var rowIds = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (i = 0; i <= rowIds.length; i++) {//iterate over each row
        rowData = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getRowData', rowIds[i]);
        if (rowData['id'] == true) { 
            $("#jDeleteButton_"+rowIds[i]).hide();
        } 
     } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), it's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. I supports `isDisplayButtons` callback of `formatter: "actions"`, which you can use to inform jqGrid about the rows, which can be deleted. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton1.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735149/315935).