# jqgrid fmatter rowcations has changed, how do I invoke the new one?

Tags: javascript, callback, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

fmatter use to be

```
$.fn.fmatter.rowactions = function(rid,gid,act,pos) {}
```

and it is now

```
$.fn.fmatter.rowactions = function(act) {}
```

where fmatter looks like this

```
$.fn.fmatter = function(formatType, cellval, opts, rwd, act) {}
```

How do I easily translate my call to the new function?  We are using the old version to delete multiple rows with selected checkboxes

Comment: You question is not full clear. Why you change the standard `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` used by `formatter: "actions"`? You can implement your own custom formatter for example. If you use free jqGrid, which I develop, then you can customize `formatter: "actions"` without overwriting `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29735149/315935) for the code examples. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton1.htm) and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton.htm).

Comment: If you do changes `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions`, then new function should be used. If it's not work then you should post the demo, which one can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Oleg, I didn't change the method.  This was changed in jqgrid version... 4.4.1 or so.  Please provide url link to your free version.  We are using latest jquery library.  Everywhere I look I end up with a licensed jqgrid version.

Comment: Free jqGrid can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) with the latest sources. I develop the fork and provide it for free under old MIT/GPL-licenses (see the readme). It can be used from CDNs (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). It's available from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) and [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid).