# Jqgrid 4.7 multiple buttons in cells. Should be dynamic

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to have a dynamic multiple buttons/images per column in a JQGrid 4.7? Each button/image should be clickable to bring up a custom modal pop up. This will only be used to display data, no editing at all.
Any code samples will be appreciated.

Here is a sample visual how it might look like:
[Dynamic buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdNpJ.png)

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Look at [the demo](https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton.htm) or at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735149/315935) or [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Enhancement-of-formatter:%22actions%22).

Comment: I use the free jqGrid. Your answer is a good start. In your demo link I see that every single row has the same number of buttons but in my case the number of buttons should vary from row to row based on the data. Ideally, I need 4 columns representing quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) Each  column will have a number of reports (buttons) that upon click will open up a modal pop up with a pdf file inside. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Free jqGrid allows to use `formatter: "actions"` or `template: "actions"` in multiple columns if you need:

```js
colModel: [
    { name: "a1", template: "actions", width: 44, align: "left",
        formatoptions: { mycol: "Q1" } },
    { name: "a2", template: "actions", width: 44, align: "left",
        formatoptions: { mycol: "Q2" } },
    ...
],
actionsNavOptions: {
    editbutton: false,// don't display Edit, Save and Cancel buttons
    delbutton: false, // don't display Delete button
    custom: [
        { action: "open", position: "first",
            onClick: function (options) {
                var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", options.rowid);
                alert("Open " + item.name + ", rowid=" + options.rowid);
            } },
        { action: "post", position: "first",
            onClick: function (options) {
                var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", options.rowid);
                alert("Post " + item.name + ", rowid=" + options.rowid);
            } }
    ],
    posticon: "fa-lock",
    posttitle: "Confirm (F2)",
    openicon: "fa-folder-open-o",
    opentitle: "Open (Enter)",
    isDisplayButtons: function (options, rowData) {
        if (options.mycol === "Q1") {
            if (rowData.closed) { // or rowData.closed
                return { post: { hidden: true } };
            }
        } else if (options.mycol === "Q2") {
            if (parseFloat(rowData.amount) < 350) { // or rowData.closed
                return { open: { hidden: true } };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With respect of `editbutton: false` and `delbutton: false` properties of `actionsNavOptions` you remove the standard actions buttons from the corresponding columns. By `custom` property one defines custom buttons and by callback `isDisplayButtons` one can include new custom buttons, include some buttons hidden or remove some custom buttons from the columns. The returned value of is described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735149/315935) and in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Enhancement-of-formatter:%22actions%22). In the way you have full control over displayed custom buttons and over the onClick behavior.

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/av7ng1u0/ as an example.